# Data consistency for Amazon Redshift tables

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, informatica

I'm trying to load and manipulate(INSERT & UPDATE) data between multiple Amazon Redshift tables using Informatica PowerCenter ODBC connection to Redshift. I read from the AWS documentation that there is an "eventual" consistency for UPDATE operations in S3. I do not see a page which talks about data consistency specifically for Redshift objects.

My question is if I should be worrying about consistency when Informatica does UPDATE operations on records and it does not happen instantly.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Are you using redshift spectrum to access s3 within redshift? Are you using copy command to read from s3?

Comment: I'm not accessing S3 directly. I'm using Informatica PowerCenter ETL tool to update Redshift table. My question is  if I run UPDATE TABLE command in Redshift, will it get updated instantly ensuring consistency.